# How to give two targets in chai expect?

Tags: chai

I have following code in my Protractor test ,

```
async function canSeeLoanPage(): Promise<void> {

    const header1 = element(by.tagName('h1')).getText();
    const header2 = element(by.css('section h1')).getText();
    try {
        await expect(header1).to.eventually.equal('Your Name');
    } catch (e) {
        await expect(header2).to.eventually.equal('Your Name');
    }  
}
```

rather checking in a try catch, what is the correct way to give two targets in expect like this?

```
await expect(header2,header2).to.eventually.equal('Your Name');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of a better way than simply using two lines of code:

```
await expect(header1).to.eventually.equal('Your Name');
await expect(header2).to.eventually.equal('Your Name');
```

Why is it you need the try catch block?

Comment: The reason I need to do this way is, the different version of applications loads a different page. So I want one a one step to verify both pages at once. try catch works because its try to do the first expect and if that is failed then the expect in the catch will check the other header

Comment: Then what's wrong with the code you have?  You simply don't want to do a try catch?

Comment: yes, rather doing try catch wnt to know any other way to handle?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  I think what you are doing is fine; there is no "right way" to accomplish something especially with new technologies like protractor.  If your code does what you want it to, I think it's right!

Comment: I thought  'try-catch' is a workaround for this matter, yes, agreed. Thanks @C.Peck